# Binding data in stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I use WPF and c#.

I have an issue regarding binding and visibility. 
I have a tree which is bound to obsCol1. Then I have a form in a grid whose datacontext is set to `

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem}">`
```

Inside that form I have 3 identical subforms if you will. Each of the 3 subforms is a groupbox inside of which is a horizontal stack panel in which there is a label textbox label textbox button.

```
<GroupBox  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                    <GroupBox.Header>Reklama 1</GroupBox.Header>
                                <StackPanel Name="Rek1" DataContext="Reklame" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Grid.Column="3"  Grid.Row="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">Datum post/zam</Label>
                                    <xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="dtReklama1" 
                                 Grid.Row="10" 
                                 Grid.Column="4"                                     
                                 Height="25" 
                                 Margin="3"
                                 Padding="3"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 Width="150" Value="{Binding Path=Opr_brendiranje}"/>                                      
                                    <Label Grid.Column="3"  Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">Dimenzija</Label>
                                    <extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="Reklama" Grid.Row="8"
                     Grid.Column="4"                         
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Width="100"
                     Height="25"
                     Padding="3" 
                     Margin="3"
                     AcceptsReturn="True" 
                     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}"
                     Validation.Error="Validation_Error">
                                        <extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
                                            <TextBox Text="Reklama" Margin="4,2,2,0" FontWeight="Regular" Foreground="Silver" BorderThickness="0"/>
                                        </extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
                                        <extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Text>
                                            <Binding Path="RekDimenzije"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True"/>
                                        </extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Text>
                                    </extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox>
                                    <Button Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="9" Height="20" Width="15" Click="Dodaj_Reklamu"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" >+</Button>
                                </StackPanel>

                </GroupBox>
```

So now I need to bind this but the issue is that these subforms use a different class from the form itself. They are an entity in and of itself. So I was wondering if there was any way to bind them independently somehow like itemsource the groupbox or the stack panel or soemthing. I tried using itemscontrol and binding to it but that did not work it would bind the itemsource but if the itemsource was empty the control would dissapear therefore not allowing the user to add it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

Ok so I have a single usercontrol.
On the left side is a tree that uses a HierarchicalDataTemplate that is bound to 2 different classes one of which OrgSredstva is OrgClass with Sredstva class contained within.

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Org_Sredstva}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Organizacije_Naziv}"/>
               <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>                     
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Ossr_Naziv}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```

This all works as complicated as it sounds the tree works fine.

On the right side is a grid that like i described above has datacontext set to whatever is selected in the tree. I need this so that when the selection changes in the tree the form changes with it. The issue is that neither of the classes the tree is bound to is the class the form should be bound to. So the grid can't find the data because the textbox bindings aren't in that observable collection but another one. The way I solved this is to bind every textbox.text property in codebehind so

```
   public void OdabranoDrvo()
    {

         OdabranaOrg = this.View.tree.SelectedItem as Organizacije;



         if (OdabranaOrg != null)
        {
            string orgId = OdabranaOrg.Organizacije_Sifra;

            IEnumerable<Opremljenost> odabranaOpr = from fn in _oprema

                                                    where fn.Opr_org_sifra == orgId

                                                    select fn;
            var ob = new ObservableCollection<Opremljenost>(odabranaOpr);


            if (ob.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Opremljenost opr in odabranaOpr)
                {
                    this.View.Povrsina.Text = opr.Opr_Povrsina.ToString();                      
                    this.View.RadnoVrijeme.Text = opr.Opr_RadnoVrijeme;
                    if (opr.Opr_Vlasnik == 1)
                    {
                        this.View.LutRad.IsChecked = true;
                        this.View.ImeVlasnika.IsReadOnly = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.View.LutRad.IsChecked = false;
                        this.View.ImeVlasnika.IsReadOnly = false;
                    }
                    this.View.ImeVlasnika.Text = opr.Opr_ime_vlasnik;
                    if (opr.Opr_brojilo == 1)
                    {
                        this.View.Brojilo.IsChecked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.View.Brojilo.IsChecked = false;
                    }
                    if (opr.Opr_ventilacija == 1)
                    {
                        this.View.Ventilacija.IsChecked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.View.Ventilacija.IsChecked = false;
                    }

                    this.View.dtBrendiranje.Value = opr.Opr_brendiranje;
                    this.View.dtKrecenje.Value = opr.Opr_krecenje;
                    this.View.Napomena.Text = opr.Opr_napomena;
                    this.View.BrojAparata.Text = opr.Opr_broj_aparata.ToString();
                    this.View.BrojRuleta.Text = opr.Opr_broj_ruleta.ToString();
                    this.View.UkupanBrojKlima.Text = opr.Opr_uku_br_klima.ToString();
                    this.View.BrojKlimaLutrija.Text = opr.Opr_br_kl_lut.ToString();
                    this.View.UkupanBrojTv.Text = opr.Opr_uku_broj_tv.ToString();
                    this.View.BrojTvLutrija.Text = opr.Opr_broj_tv_lut.ToString();
                    this.View.BrojTvPartneri.Text = opr.Opr_broj_tv_partneri.ToString();
                    this.View.StrujnaSnaga.Text = opr.Opr_struja_ang_snaga.ToString();
                    _slikeOpr = Ap.GlavniRepository.UcitajSlikeZaOpremu(opr.Opr_Id);
                    this.View.Thumbnails.ItemsSource = _slikeOpr;


                    _reklame = Ap.GlavniRepository.UcitajReklameZaOpremu(opr.Opr_Id);
                    int i = _reklame.Count();

                    if (i == 2)
                    {
                        this.View.Rek2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        this.View.Rek3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    else if (i == 3)
                    {
                        this.View.Rek2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        this.View.Rek3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.View.Rek2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        this.View.Rek3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    this.View.Reklame.DataContext = _reklame;


                }

            }
            else
            {
                this.View.Povrsina.Text = "0";
                this.View.RadnoVrijeme.Text = String.Empty;
                this.View.LutRad.IsChecked=false;
                this.View.ImeVlasnika.Text = String.Empty;
                this.View.Brojilo.IsChecked = false;
                this.View.Ventilacija.IsChecked = false;
                this.View.dtBrendiranje.Value = DateTime.Now;
                this.View.dtKrecenje.Value = DateTime.Now;
                this.View.Napomena.Text = String.Empty;
                this.View.BrojAparata.Text = "0";
                this.View.BrojRuleta.Text = "0";
                this.View.UkupanBrojKlima.Text = "0";
                this.View.BrojKlimaLutrija.Text = "0";
                this.View.UkupanBrojTv.Text = "0";
                this.View.BrojTvLutrija.Text = "0";
                this.View.BrojTvPartneri.Text = "0";
                this.View.StrujnaSnaga.Text = "0";
                this.View.Thumbnails.ItemsSource = null;
                this.View.Rek2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                this.View.Rek3.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

The original question i resolved by creating a new grid inside my preexisting grid and just setting the data context for that inner grid to what I needed it to be. Now I find that all the bindings seem to work at least on reading from database, haven't tested inserting into database yet.

I realise this is all very ugly but I couldn't figure out a way to actually bind it while it still working as it should...

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the problem, and structure your trying to describe. Would it be possible to do a quick (very simplified) sketch of what you want, and maybe how your classes relate?

Comment: I figured it out using a grid inside a grid and setting the context of the other grid. But since i don't like the way i did it ill do it hoping someone will come up with a better solution.